# Legend does not fit well ggplot density

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, legend

I am doing a plot of densities, I want to add a legend but is overlapped with the symbol. The code is hereunder:

```
dfGamma = data.frame(a = rgamma(100,shape = 7.1,rate= 0.0055),
                     b = rgamma(100, shape = 10,rate= 0.0055),
                     c = rgamma(100, shape = 7.1,rate= 0.0055))

dfGamma = stack(dfGamma)
p <- ggplot(dfGamma, aes(x = values)) +
  stat_density(aes(group = ind, colour = ind),position="identity",geom="line",size=1)+
  ggtitle("Gamma distribution")+theme(legend.position="right")+
  scale_color_manual(labels = c(expression(paste(alpha,"=7.1 ",beta,"=0.0055")),
                                expression(paste(alpha,"= 10 ",beta,"=0.0055")),
                                expression(paste(alpha,"=7.1 ",beta,"=0.0055"))),
                     values = c('red', 'blue',"green"))

p
```

the plot is:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `guides` option, `guide_legend` is what you need. You can read more about it [in the ggplot reference](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html). Does this help?

```
p <- ggplot(dfGamma, aes(x = values)) +
  stat_density(aes(group = ind, colour = ind),position="identity",geom="line",size=1)+
  ggtitle("Gamma distribution")+
  theme(legend.position="right") +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c(expression(paste(alpha, "=7.1 ", beta, "=0.0055")),
                                expression(paste(alpha,"= 10 ",beta,"=0.0055")),
                                expression(paste(alpha,"=7.1 ",beta,"=0.0055"))),
                     values = c('red', 'blue',"green")) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(label.position = "bottom"))

p
```

[image]